# Multiple PHP versions running as cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cgi, php-cgi

I'm trying to install a second version of PHP, to run alongside the current version of php.
I've compiled the latest php source from github (5.5-DEV), and I'm trying to run it as CGI.

Here is my virtual host config:

```apache
<VirtualHost *:8055>
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/php55/cgi

    Action php55-cgi /cgi-bin/php-cgi
    AddHandler php55-cgi .php

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8055/info.ph`p, I get the following error:

**Forbidden**

`You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/php-cgi/info.php on this server`

**Edit**

I'm now switching between

```apache
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/local/php54/libphp5.so
```

and

```apache
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/local/php55/libphp5.so
```

It works for now, but is not ideal.
I would like to have the different versions of php on different virtual hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to tell Apache how to handle the system's new `/usr/local/php55` directory.

```apache
<Directory /usr/local/php55/cgi>
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You might need to add an extra "**/**" at the end `ScriptAlias` assignment, or the `Action` may resolve to

```apache
Action php55-cgi /usr/local/php55/cgiphp-cgi
```

So your vhost block would read as:

```apache
<VirtualHost *:8055>
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/php55/cgi/

    Action php55-cgi /cgi-bin/php-cgi
    AddHandler php55-cgi .php

    <Directory /usr/local/php55/cgi>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```